# How do I import a file to execute a function

Tags: python-3.x, file, import

I have a file with a function. I want to import the file and when doing that I get No module named ex25.

import ex25

I have checked some tutorials and the offial documentation.

> > > import ex25
> > >       No module named ex25

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the file is `.py` file and in the same folder with the file that you are currently working on, there shouldn't be any problem at all. 
If not in the same folder, but in a different folder and make sure that your file is `.py` file, you need to make that folder (which contains the file) to a package by adding a file name `__init__.py`

Comment: I can suggest that you can try this `from LPTHW import ex25` and let me know the output.

Comment: I got it! what I had to do is to place the ex25 file inside mi user folder. Thanks for your help.